# Importing data from multiple sheets with Query/ImportRange formula returning ARRAYLITERAL ERROR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I have 2 Google Sheets which track class attendance for our two main sites and each tab on the sheet is a different class/course. Each sheet has a "data" tab which pulls all the class/course data. I am trying to pull the data sheets from these two sheets and put them on a 3rd sheet and organize the class data by a program (GED, CDP, ESL). I have had no issues pulling the data from one sheet, but when I tried stacking the `Query` and `Importrange` formulas, I keep receiving an **ARRAY LITERAL error** that there is a missing row.

My original formula was

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1avE5TJIDVNL7_wqjDLPgocZuecr5Aoz7aI3cI5yIe34", "Data!A3:Ak1000"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 WHERE Col3 CONTAINS 'ESL' AND Col7>0");QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10q7kBUJVTw62p1cCZjUIR1CsFSev9Ik6q4K-X-RK40Y", "Data!A3:Ak1000"), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 WHERE Col3 CONTAINS 'ESL' AND Col7>0")}
```

and it gave a `VALUE` error message that the `ARRAY LITERAL` was missing rows.

Based on other's recommendations from other sites, I tried the formula (below), but received a formula parse ERROR message and tried moving the curly brackets to just around the ImportRange formula, but continued to receive a formula parse ERROR MESSAGE

```
=QUERY{(IMPORTRANGE("1avE5TJIDVNL7_wqjDLPgocZuecr5Aoz7aI3cI5yIe34", "Data!A3:Ak1000");IMPORTRANGE("10q7kBUJVTw62p1cCZjUIR1CsFSev9Ik6q4K-X-RK40Y", "Data!A3:Ak1000")},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col26, Col27, Col28, Col29 WHERE Col3 CONTAINS 'ESL' AND Col7>0")
```

I expect that the output will list any classes that contain "ESL" in Col3 and the corresponding columns from both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

## understanding **ARRAY_LITERAL ERROR**:

if both queries output something then all is good:

[image: 0]

however if one of those queries doesn't have anything to output it outputs `#N/A` but the issue is that `#N/A` is only in the 1st cell:

[image: e]

but array expects that matrix on both sides to be same (4 columns from both queries):

[image: 0]

so we wrap each query into `IFERROR` and in case of error we output fake row with 4 fake columns - **`{"","","",""}`** - which will trick the array to output it like:

[image: 0]

therefore try like this:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
  "1avE5TJIDVNL7_wqjDLPgocZuecr5Aoz7aI3cI5yIe34", "Data!A3:AK1000"), 
  "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col26,Col27,Col28,Col29 
   where Col3 contains 'ESL' 
   and Col7>0", 0), {"","","","","","","","","","",""});
  IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "10q7kBUJVTw62p1cCZjUIR1CsFSev9Ik6q4K-X-RK40Y", "Data!A3:AK1000"), 
  "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col26,Col27,Col28,Col29 
   where Col3 contains 'ESL'
   and Col7>0", 0), {"","","","","","","","","","",""})}, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

Comment: I tried the formula above, but it only returned the values from the first sheet and not the second sheet "10q7kBUJVTw62p1cCZjUIR1CsFSev9Ik6q4K-X-RK40Y".

Comment: can you share your sheets?